# Selecting the most popular keyword in a mysql database

Tags: mysql, keyword, explode

I have a column called keywords where users enter up to 4 keywords separated by a coma, ie:

```
----------------------------------
userId |    kewords              |
----------------------------------
01     | php,css,html,mysql      |
02     | wordpress,css,drupal,xx |
03     | mysql,html,wordpress,css|
----------------------------------
```

I'm trying to figure out a query to select all the keywords from everyone, explode them by the coma and then count how many there are of each.

I know I can do this quite easily with PHP but I though there might be a way for mysql to do it...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try to normalize the data, ie store 4 rows instead of one for each user.

It also possible to split a string into a temporary table but I'm not sure that will help you much. Originally I found this source on mysql forge but that has been shut down so here is a similar code

http://www.pnplogic.com/blog/articles/MySQL_Convert_Delimited_String_To_Temp_Table_Result_Set.php